# Unable to change video in Binded Mediaelement with MediaTimeline RepeatBehavior="Forever"

Tags: wpf, video, binding, repeat, mediaelement

I want to have a video repeating forever until in my viewmodel I change the video source. But i'am not able to achive this 2 behaviors togheter.
I'm using this axml:

```
<MediaElement Name="myMediaElement" Margin="10" LoadedBehavior="Play">
<MediaElement.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MediaElement.Loaded">
        <EventTrigger.Actions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <MediaTimeline Source="{Binding FaseTest.VideoUri}"
                    Storyboard.TargetName="myMediaElement" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger.Actions>
    </EventTrigger>
</MediaElement.Triggers>
```

If i **dont'** use Trigger changing video works but i dont't have the repeating behavior.
If i **use** Trigger repeating behavior work but changing video not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved using a an eventhandler for the mediaelement and removing the eventtriggers and mediatimeline:

```
<MediaElement Name="myMediaElement" Margin="10" Source="{Binding FaseTest.VideoUri}" 
 LoadedBehavior="Play" UnloadedBehavior="Manual" MediaEnded="MediaEnded" >
```

and

```
private void MediaEnded( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
    {
        myMediaElement.Position = TimeSpan.Zero;
        myMediaElement.Play();
    }
```

I know that this is a little bit dirty... but i'am unable to find another working solution without using backcoding.